# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I know this is asked many times, but I can not figure it out.

I have dataset in this format. First 767 columns are for training and have training data. Next 669 columns are labels.

Labels are in the format of one hot vector i.e [0,0,0......1,0,0]. So I have 669 columns. Now I want to perform training on it using XGBoost. My code is.

```py
self.clf = XGBClassifier(objective="multi:softmax", num_classes=669)
data = single_data.iloc[:, 0:767]
label = single_data.iloc[:, 767:]
self.clf.fit(data, label)
```

The error I get is

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1638, 670) instead.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: It's telling you not to one hot encode your labels - just use a single column, where each class has a different number

Comment: is there any way to use one hot?

Comment: convert your one hot to clases. i think the easiest way is `lab = np.argmax(label,axis=1) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
label = pd.DataFrame({'c0':[0,1,0,0,0], 'c1':[1,0,0,0,0], 'c2':[0,0,1,1,0], 'c3':[0,0,0,0,1]})
print(label)
```

Output

```
   c0  c1  c2  c3
0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   1
```

The convert them to integers

```
label = label.apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1).values
```

Now your labels look like this, a single array:

```
array([1, 0, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```